# A href click triggers select option's dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

It is a project that's meant to be used on mobiles so there's no need to think how it would behave on desktop screens. In my project, I have an "a href" with an icon next to it that looks like a button. When an user clicks on it, then it opens "select option" dropdown menu. On mobiles, it would look like an radio button on Android or picker on iPhone by default. Sample image of select option on Android is below.

[image: Select option dropdown on Android]

User makes a selection as they would on their phones, and after clicking it reverts back to original "a href" that looks like a button. However, "select option" should not be visible and only show after "a href" click in opened dropdown list form.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="button-select"><i class="icon">Icon</i> Button</a>
<select id="button-dropdown">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.button-select').trigger(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When you click on "a href," it opens "select option" dropdown menu that looks as you can see on a picture. And after clicking on any option, it goes back to "a href" as usual. 
My Jquery skills are relatively weak and I am asking your help how to achieve that. Since it is "a href," I had used "e.preventDefault();" but I don't know how to go on.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: show select box on click of anchor href and hide it on change event of select box. See below code

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.button-select').on('click',function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#button-dropdown').show();
});
 $('#button-dropdown').on('change', function(){
   $(this).hide();
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a href="#" class="button-select"><i class="icon">Icon</i> Button</a>
<select id="button-dropdown" style="display:none">
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```